# Complement List of a sub List

Tags: c#, generics, list, extension-methods

```
listSuper
listSub_A
listSub_B
```

Are there any extension methods that replace the following piece of code?

```
 foreach(int a in listSuper)
 {
 if (!listSub_A.Contains(a))
 {
 listSub_B.Add(a);
 }
 }
```

In short I want to fill listSub_B with elements in listSuper which are not in listSub_A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
listSub_B.AddRange(listSuper.Except(listSub_A));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a property rather than an extension method since you wont need to update listSub_B if listSub_A changes?

```
public ...  listSub_B
{
  get{return listSuper.Except(listSub_A);}
}
```